# Cannot commit error: Load key "path": invalid format?

Tags: github, ssh, commit

When I tried to commit my work I've this message :

```bash
error: Load key "/var/folders/97/8chxzhxs3n79g9b95510jwwr0000gn/T//.git_signing_key_tmp2JvaYk": invalid format?

fatal: failed to write commit object
```

Please can help me, I can't commit anything.

I see many topics about this with ssh-add and ss-agent but none works for my case...

I've tried to regenerate my ssh key with ssh-keygen. I've remove my `id_rsa` and `id_rsa.pub` to regenerate them.

Question : the message is -> `error: Load key "/var/folders/97/8chxzhxs3n79g9b95510jwwr0000gn/T//.git_signing_key_tmp2JvaYk": invalid format?`

But my key are located in `~/.ssh/id_rsa...` I don't understand.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If your private key is passphrase-protected (meaning, encrypted), you would need to add your SSH key to an SSH agent.
Check also "[Signing Git Commits with Your SSH Key](https://calebhearth.com/sign-git-with-ssh#:%7E:text=configured%20signing%20correctly.-,Verifying,-Git%20also%20lets)" from [Caleb Hearth](https://calebhearth.com/about).

Only then a `git commit -S` (signing the commit) would work.
Or you might have [told Git about your SSH key](https://docs.github.com/en/authentication/managing-commit-signature-verification/telling-git-about-your-signing-key#telling-git-about-your-ssh-key):

```
git config --global gpg.format ssh
git config --global user.signingkey 'key::ssh-ed25519 AAAAC3(...) user@example.com'
```

---

Note that, with Git 2.40 (Q1 2023), the error message is improved when private key is not loaded in the SSH agent in the codepath to sign with an SSH key.

See [commit dce7b31](https://github.com/git/git/commit/dce7b311266951fc2fb7a1dcbe89416ba8cebbb5) (25 Jan 2023) by [Adam Szkoda (`adaszko`)](https://github.com/adaszko).
<sup>(Merged by [Junio C Hamano -- `gitster` --](https://github.com/gitster) in [commit c7757b2](https://github.com/git/git/commit/c7757b2781084ceb982ab9422011ff88e49180a0), 03 Feb 2023)</sup>

> ### [`ssh signing`](https://github.com/git/git/commit/dce7b311266951fc2fb7a1dcbe89416ba8cebbb5): better error message when key not in agent
>
> <sup>Signed-off-by: Adam Szkoda</sup>

> When signing a commit with a SSH key, with the private key missing from ssh-agent, a confusing error message is produced:
>
> ```
> error: Load key
> "/var/folders/t5/cscwwl_n3n1_8_5j_00x_3t40000gn/T//.git_signing_key_tmpkArSj7":
> invalid format? fatal: failed to write commit object
> ```
>
> The temporary file `.git_signing_key_tmpkArSj7` created by Git contains a valid *public* key.
> The error message comes from `ssh-keygen -Y sign' and is caused by a fallback mechanism in` ssh-keygen`whereby it tries to interpret`.git_signing_key_tmpkArSj7` as a *private* key [if it can't find in the agent](https://bugzilla.mindrot.org/show_bug.cgi?id=3429).
>
> A fix is scheduled to be released in OpenSSH 9.1.
>
> All that needs to be done is to pass an additional backward-compatible option `-U` to '`ssh-keygen -Y sign`' call.
> With '-U', `ssh-keygen` always interprets the file as public key and expects to find the private key in the agent.
>
> As a result, when the private key is missing from the agent, a more accurate error message gets produced:
>
> ```
> error: Couldn't find key in agent
> ```

Comment: git config --global works well and solve my problem ! thank's

Answer (score 0):

This command did the trick for me:

```
$ git config --global gpg.format ssh
```